# python error unreconized arguments when run specific function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script which I just want to run a function within the script

```
python testfile.py _test_one_xml --password Test123! --username TESTER
```

The cmd returned error:

```
testfile.py: error: unrecognized arguments: _test_one_xml
```

script :

```
  #!/usr/bin/python3
"""
 ABSTRACT:  Package for load tickets
 COMPILER:  Python3.4
"""
import os                                                                      # import python package operationg system
import sys                                                                     # import python package system
import datetime                                                                # import python package date time
import shutil                                                                  # import python package shell utilities
import glob                                                                    # import python package glob
import argparse                                                                # import python package argument parser
import requests                                                                # import python package for l1tc requests
import time                                                                    # import python package time
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET                                             # import python package for xml handling
from requests.packages import urllib3                                          # import python package urllib3 for request

# suspress ssl verification warnings
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

# main method for loading tickets to prjABC
def _load_tickets():                                                           # method definition

   # parse command line arguments
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Loads tickets to prjABC.", formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
   parser.add_argument('-p', '--password', help="set password", default='tester!')
   parser.add_argument('-u', '--username', help="set user name", default='tester')
   args = parser.parse_args()

   # check if user name or password are valid
   if args.username == '' or args.password == '':
      print('Username or password is missing.')
      sys.exit()

   # load tickets
   _load_tickets_from_prjABC_directory(args.username, args.password)

# method loads prjABC test plans for check if product and version in ticket matches
# then all test suites and test cases will be loaded to get STP-DB ID
# if Test ID from ticket and STP-DB ID in prjABC are equal ticket is valid
def _load_tickets_from_prjABC_directory(sUserName, sPassword):

   # local variables
   sDirTransfer                = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('\\\\RSINT.NET', 'DATA', 'MU', 'SATURN', 'PROJECT', '1ES', 'EMIL', 'SW', 'TEST', 'Doc', 'STP', 'transfer'))
   sDirprjABCNew                  = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(sDirTransfer, 'prjABC', 'new'))
   sDirprjABCInProgress           = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(sDirTransfer, 'prjABC', 'inprogress'))
   sDirprjABCAssessed             = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(sDirTransfer, 'prjABC', 'assessed'))
   sDirprjABCFailed               = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(sDirTransfer, 'prjABC', 'failed'))
   sDirprjABCInvalid              = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(sDirTransfer, 'prjABC', 'invalid'))

   sUrlServer                  = 'https://test123.net/resources/'
   sProjectArea                = 'Project ONE'
   sUrlProjectArea             = 'https://test123.netProjectArea/_aruiy997Fiyr3213fef'


   sUrlTestPlan                = sUrlServer + sProjectArea + '/testplan'
   lprjABCTestPlanName            = []
   lprjABCTestPlanID              = []
   lprjABCTestCaseExecutionRecord = []
   dicprjABCTestCaseList          = {}
   dicprjABCTestCaseID            = {}
   dicprjABCTestCaseName          = {}
   iIdx                        = 0
   bValid                      = True

   # print info
   print('Dir prjABC New: '+sDirprjABCNew)
   print('Load prjABC Test Plan Names and IDs.')

   lProducts = ['A', 'C', 'Z']
   for sProduct in lProducts:
      # create request for single product
      sUrlProduct = sUrlTestPlan + '?fields=feed/entry/content/testplan[category/@term="Instrument" and category/@value="' + sProduct + '" and state!="com.ibm.prjABC.planning.common.retired"]/*'
      # load prjABC test plan names and ids
      lProductprjABCTestPlanName = []
      lProductprjABCTestPlanID   = []
      lProductprjABCTestPlanName, lProductprjABCTestPlanID = _get_all_test_plans(sUrlProduct, sUserName, sPassword)
      # append results to global test plan lists
      lprjABCTestPlanID   = lprjABCTestPlanID   + lProductprjABCTestPlanID
      lprjABCTestPlanName = lprjABCTestPlanName + lProductprjABCTestPlanName

   # initialize lists containing test cases
   for name in lprjABCTestPlanName:
      dicprjABCTestCaseList[name] = []
      iIdx += 1

   # loop over all tickets in prjABC new directory
   for sTicket in glob.glob(sDirprjABCNew + os.sep + "*.tic"):

      # get modification date of ticket and current time
      sTimeMod = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(sTicket))
      sTimeMod = sTimeMod.split(' ')
      sTimeMod = sTimeMod[3]
      sTimeNow = str(datetime.datetime.now())
      sTimeNow = sTimeNow.split(' ')
      sTimeNow = sTimeNow[1].split('.')
      sTimeNow = sTimeNow[0]

      # skip current ticket if modification time is now 
      if sTimeMod == sTimeNow:
         continue

      print('Ticket: '+sTicket)
      bValid = False

      # load values from current ticket
      dicTicket = _get_ticket_values(sTicket)

      # check if result file is a memory file
      if dicTicket['File'].endswith('.mem') or dicTicket['File Type'] == 'Memory File':
         print('Skip ticket containing memory data.')
      #elif int(dicTicket['Version Sideline']) > 99:
      #   print('Skip ticket for release sidelines.')
      elif dicTicket['ConfTest Version'] != '-':
         print('Skip ticket from Confidence Test.')
      else:
         # set test plan name
         sprjABCTestPlanName = dicTicket['Product'] + ' ' + dicTicket['Version'] + ' MU'
         sprjABCTestPlanID   = ''

         print('prjABC Test Plan Name: ' + sprjABCTestPlanName)
         print('Searching for Test Plan \"' + sprjABCTestPlanName + '\".')

         iIdx = 0

         # loop over all test plans
         for name in lprjABCTestPlanName:

            # check if current test plan matches product and version
            if name == sprjABCTestPlanName:

               # get current test plan id
               sprjABCTestPlanID = lprjABCTestPlanID[iIdx]

               # check if test cases for current test plan was not loaded
               if len(dicprjABCTestCaseList.get(name)) == 0:

                  lTestSuites = _get_all_test_suites_from_test_plan(sprjABCTestPlanID, sUserName, sPassword)
                  for TestSuites in lTestSuites:
                     print('Test Suites: ' + TestSuites)
                     lCases = _get_all_test_cases_from_test_suite(TestSuites, sUserName, sPassword)
                     for sCase in lCases:
                        dicprjABCTestCaseList[name].append(sCase)

                  lCases = _get_all_test_cases_from_test_plan(sprjABCTestPlanID, sUserName, sPassword)
                  for sCase in lCases:
                     dicprjABCTestCaseList[name].append(sCase)

            iIdx += 1

         # check if test cases for current test plan was not loaded
         if not dicprjABCTestCaseList.get(sprjABCTestPlanName):
            print('Test Plan \"' + sprjABCTestPlanName + '\" was not found.')
         else:
            print('Test Plan \"' + sprjABCTestPlanName + '\" was found.')
            print('Searching for Test Case with STP-ID \"' + dicTicket['Test ID'] + '\" (' + str(int(dicTicket['Test ID'], 16)) + ').')

            # loop over all test cases from current test plan
            for sTC in dicprjABCTestCaseList.get(sprjABCTestPlanName):

               # check if current test case was not loaded
               if not dicprjABCTestCaseID.get(sTC):

                  # load stp-db id and name from current test case
                  iprjABCSTPID, sprjABCTestName = _get_all_infos_from_test_case(sTC, sUserName, sPassword)

                  # save stp-db id and name from current test case
                  dicprjABCTestCaseID  [sTC] = iprjABCSTPID
                  dicprjABCTestCaseName[sTC] = sprjABCTestName

               print('Test Case: '+dicprjABCTestCaseName.get(sTC)+', Test ID: '+str(dicprjABCTestCaseID.get(sTC)))

               # check if stp-db id is test id from ticket
               if dicprjABCTestCaseID.get(sTC) == str(int(dicTicket['Test ID'], 16)):
                  print('Test Case was found.')
                  bValid           = True
                  sState, sContent = _get_ticket_file_content(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(sDirprjABCNew, dicTicket['File'])))
                  sState           = _assess_special_tests(dicTicket['Test ID'], sState, sContent)
                  _test_one_xml(sprjABCTestPlanID, sTC, dicTicket, sState, sContent, sUrlServer, sProjectArea, sUrlProjectArea, sUserName, sPassword)

      # set tag
      sTag = dicTicket['Version Major'] + '.' + dicTicket['Version Minor'] + '.' + dicTicket['Version Revision'] + '.' + dicTicket['Version Sideline']

      # use version as tag for all not ES-MAIN devices
      if dicTicket['Version Major'] == '' and dicTicket['Version Minor'] == '' and dicTicket['Version Revision'] == '' and dicTicket['Version Sideline'] == '' and not dicTicket['Version'] == '':
         sTag = dicTicket['Version']

      # check is ticket is invalid
      if bValid == False:
         # set destination directory
         sDirDst = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(sDirprjABCInvalid, dicTicket['Product'], sTag))

         # create directory structure
         _create_directory_structure(sDirprjABCInvalid, dicTicket['Product'], sTag)

      # check if ticket is valid
      else:
         # check state of ticket to determine output directory
         if sState == 'com.ibm.prjABC.execution.common.state.inprogress':
            # set destination directory
            sDirDst = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(sDirprjABCInProgress, dicTicket['Product'], sTag))

            # create directory structure
            _create_directory_structure(sDirprjABCInProgress, dicTicket['Product'], sTag)

         # check state of ticket to determine output directory
         if sState == 'com.ibm.prjABC.execution.common.state.passed':
            # set destination directory
            sDirDst = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(sDirprjABCAssessed, dicTicket['Product'], sTag))

            # create directory structure
            _create_directory_structure(sDirprjABCAssessed, dicTicket['Product'], sTag)

         # check state of ticket to determine output directory
         if sState == 'com.ibm.prjABC.execution.common.state.failed':
            # set destination directory
            sDirDst = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(sDirprjABCFailed, dicTicket['Product'], sTag))

            # create directory structure
            _create_directory_structure(sDirprjABCFailed, dicTicket['Product'], sTag)

      # copy ticket and result file to destination directory
      shutil.copy(sTicket, sDirDst)
      shutil.copy(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(sDirprjABCNew, dicTicket['File'])), sDirDst)

      # delete ticket and result file in source directory
      try:
         os.remove(sTicket)
         os.remove(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(sDirprjABCNew, dicTicket['File'])))
      except ValueError:
         print('Error: Could not delete file. Maybe its used by another process.')



# method writes xml with test case result data and uploads it to prjABC
def _test_one_xml(sTestPlan, sTestCase, dicTicket, sState, sContent, sUrlServer, sProjectArea, sUrlProjectArea, username, password):
   username                    = 'tester'
   password                    = 'tester!'
   # determine current date and time and format it
   sDateTime = str(datetime.datetime.now())
   sDateTime = sDateTime[:-3] + 'Z'
   sDateTime = sDateTime.replace(' ', 'T')
   

   # set content for xml file
   sCreator                 = username.upper()
   sOwner                   = dicTicket['Tester'].upper()
   sMachine                 = os.environ['COMPUTERNAME']
   sTestCaseExecutionRecord = _get_test_case_execution_record(sTestPlan, sTestCase, dicTicket, sUrlServer, sProjectArea, username, password)

   # check if test case execution record was found
   if sTestCaseExecutionRecord is None:
      print("Test Case Record was not found.")
      return

   # get title and test script
   sTitle          = _get_title_from_test_case_execution_record(sTestCaseExecutionRecord, username, password)
   sTestScript     = _get_test_script_from_test_case(sTestCase, username, password)
   sDescription    = ''
   sExceptedResult = ''

   # use computer name from ticket if exist
   if not dicTicket['PC Name'] == '':
      sMachine = dicTicket['PC Name']

   # set tag from ticket data and get build record
   sTag         = 'ES-MAIN_' + dicTicket['Version Major'] + '.' + dicTicket['Version Minor'] + '.' + dicTicket['Version Revision'] + '.' + dicTicket['Version Sideline']
   sBuildRecord = _get_build_record(sUrlServer, sProjectArea, sUrlProjectArea, sTag, username, password)

   # check if test script exists
   if not sTestScript == '':
      # get description and expected result from test script
      sDescription, sExceptedResult = _get_description_from_test_script(sTestScript, username, password)

 

   # test case results
   url     = sUrlServer + sProjectArea + '/executionresult'
   headers = {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
   fobj    = open("testcaseresult.xml", "r")
   xml     = fobj.read()
   fobj.close()

   print(xml)
   r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=xml, auth=(username, password), verify=False)
   print (r.content)

   # remove test case results
   if os.path.exists("testcaseresult.xml"):
      os.remove("testcaseresult.xml")

def _main():                                                                   # main method definition
   _load_tickets()                                                             # call method _load_tickets

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                     # check if load_tickets.py is called by repl
   _main()                                                                     # call main method
```

Comment: It's not recognizing ```_test_one_xml``` as a valid argument.  You've only defined ```-u``` and ```-p``` as valid arguments.

Comment: you define two arg but you give 3, _test_one_xml not defined in you argparse

Comment: how do I run the function '_test_one_xml'?